# Are these languages context free or not?

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

1. $L_1=\{a^nb^mc^nd^m \mid m,n >0\}$
2. $L_2=\{a^nb^mc^md^n \mid m,n >0 \}$
3. $L_3=\{a^mb^n \mid m+n\text{ is a prime number}\}$
4. $L_4=\{a^mb^n \mid n=m^2\}$
5. $L_5=\big\{ww^R\#ww^R \mid w \in \{a,b\}^* \big\}$
6. $L_6=\big\{wuw^R \mid |w|=|u|, w,u \in \{a,b\}^* \big\}$
7. $L_7=\big\{wu \mid |w|=|u|, w,u \in\{a,b\}^*\big\}$
8. $L_8=\{a^mb^nc^k \mid k \le \min(m,n) \}$
9. $L_9=\{a^mb^nc^k \mid k \le \max(m,n) \}$

thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you format your items using [**MathJax**](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make them more readable? Regards!

Comment: That is **way** too much to put in a single question; please bread this into several questions. It would also be a very good idea to give some indication of what ideas you’ve had towards answering at least some of them.

Comment: May be http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is more fit for this question?

Comment: First try creating a context-free grammar for these languages and if you are unable to do so ,use pummping lemma to prove they are not context free.

Comment: @Mohan: We deal with this kind of question quite often at MSE.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  In addition to MathJax, we like to see questions that show people's work.  This has two benefits: 1) We can answer your question more effectively if we can see exactly where you got stuck. 2) You are more likely to get answers, as people appreciate the work you've put in to solving the problems.

If you don't even know where to begin, it is also helpful to state that.

Comment: LOL!! can't believe someone from my class just copied paste the whole exercise :))
I currently stuck at 8&9

Answer (score 8):

A few HINTS:

- It’s extremely easy to write down a context-free grammar that generates $L_7$.
- It’s almost as easy to come up with a context-free grammar that generates $L_2$: design it to generate the $a$’s and $d$’s simultaneously first, and then the $b$’s and $c$’s simultaneously.
- The [Bar-Hillel pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) will settle $L_1,L_5$, and $L_7$ very easily, and $L_3$ and $L_4$ with just a bit more work.

Now that you at least have some pointers in the right direction, try to make some progress on a few of these, and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: What about $L_8$ and $L_9$ ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a long question, so, I´ll give you a quickly anwser: you must use the Pumping Lemma for Context Free Languages (CFL). In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) you can read more about it. Also [here](http://www.cse.nd.edu/courses/cse30151/www/cfl-pumping-lemma.pdf) you find examples of how to prove that a language is not CFL.

Answer (score 0):

1) We can prove that $L_1$ doesn't satisfy the conditions of pumping lemma

Let the pumping length be $n$. Now consider the string $S=a^nb^nc^nd^n$.We must decompose $S$ in to $uvxyz$ such that it satisfies conditions of pumping lemma. So, what can be $u,v,x,y$ and $z$ be equal to so that conditions of pumping lemma are satified?  We know that $|vxy| \leq n$. Check the following cases

1.$vxy$ can't consist only of $a$'s and $b$'s.Because if $v=a^i$ and $u=b^k$, $a^{n+i}b^{n+k}c^nd^n \notin L$.

2.Using a similar reasoning to prove that $vxy$ can't consist of $b$'s and $c$'s.

3.$vxy$ also can't consist of $c$'s and $d$'s in a similar way.

So, we have have proved that the string $S$ can't be decomposed in to $uvxyz$ such that it satisfies the conditions of pumping lemma. That means $L$ is not context free.