# Is the language $=\{^.^.^j.^i:,≥0\}$ context free language?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Is the language $=\{^.^.^j.^i:,≥0\}$ context free language?
If yes, what is the context-free grammar?

Comment: This should go on the Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Parcly_Taxel This question is perfectly on topic here. There is a "context-free grammar" tag just for this kind of questions.

Comment: A [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276132/are-these-languages-context-free-or-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is a context free language. The Context Free Grammar for this would be:
$$
S \rightarrow aSd\ |\ B\\
B \rightarrow bBc\ |\ e
$$
Where $e$ is the empty charachter. You can arrive at this by looking at a similar Language which has an easier to guess grammar, $L^{'}=\{a^{n}b^{n}:n\ge0\}$, which has the grammar $S^{'}\rightarrow\ aSb\ |\ e$.